# Publishing website is freezing

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, publishing

From some moment publishing to Azure web site is freezing. I use Visual Studio 2017 (ver. 4.7.02558):

[image]

and it's freezing on this point. I even can't imagine how to search a solution to solve it...

Comment: Have you try update/fix Visual Studio or delete publishing profile and create new?

Comment: @Lit, yes, tried both options

Comment: Try to update the azure sdk to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to isolate the issue to see if it only freezes publishing to Azure WebApps. If it freezes everywhere its perhaps VS or system issue. As highlighted by Lit and Joy, update VS, install latest SDK. Try installing the latest Windows Update and reboot the system and then re-try the operation. To further isolate, test this on another system running VS.